# C++ dynamic cast with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, dynamic-cast

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void foo() { cout << "foo in A" << endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo() { cout << "foo in B" << endl; }
};


int main() {
    A* a = new B;
    a->foo(); // will print "foo in A" because foo is not virtual
    B* b = new B;
    b->foo(); // will print "foo in B" because static type of b is B

    // the problem
    A* ab;
    ab = dynamic_cast<B*>(new B);
    ab->foo(); // will print "foo in A" !!!!!
}
```

Does the 'dynamic_cast' not change the static type of ab? I mean, logically, it seams equivalent to B* ab = new B; because of the casting.. But it does not.
I thought that dynamic cast changes the static type of the object, am I wrong?  And if so, what is the difference between:

```
A* ab = dynamic_cast<B*>(new B);
```

and

```
A* ab = new B;
```

Thanks

Comment: Think of what `dynamic_cast<B*>` is being applied to. What is the type of `new B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `dynamic_cast`ing to B, but at time of assignment to ab, you are *implicitely* casting back to A, so the dynamic_cast gets lost again.

The actual type of the object ab is pointing to still remains B, but the pointer the object is accessed with is of type A, so A::foo is selected. It would have been different if foo was virtual, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the foo() function from A pointer, foo() of class A will be called. I believe you're looking for a virtual behavior.
If that is the case, declare foo() of class A as:

```
virtual void foo() { cout << "foo in A" << endl; }
```